# How to get impact point On Component End Overlap?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am using unreal engine 4.26 for my project,
I have to get "Impact Point" when End Overlap Event is called, What can I do for this?
Both blueprint and c++ are ok :)

Comment: If you can tick the actor you could save the impact point of overlapped actor and update it every frame, when you end overlap you'll have the last impact point. If you can't use tick I would use a timer, start the timer on "OnBeginOverlap", the timer will call a function that will get the overlapped actor of your interest and update a class variable with the current impact point. Whenever you call "OnEndOverlap" stop the timer and use the updated variable. If you need I'll add code in blueprints but it should be clear.

Comment: Thanks for advice, It helps a lot!! :)

Comment: If you could upvote it may helps other with same problem :)